# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, stuck at a practice

Tags: python

```
def ConverttoDictionary(list):
 global dictionary
 dictionary = {}
 x=list.count("gold coin")
 y=list.count("dagger")
 z=list.count("ruby")
 for i in ["x","y","z"]:
    dictionary[i]=eval(i)
     return dictionary
def  addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
  global finalinventory
  finalinventory={**inventory, **addedItems}
  return finalinventory
inventory={'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
 print("Inventory:")
 for key, value in inventory.items():
 print(f"{key}: {value}")
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
ConverttoDictionary(dragonLoot)
addToInventory(inventory, dictionary)
print("new inventory:")
for key, value in finalinventory.items():
  print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
Inventory:
rope: 1
torch: 6
gold coin: 42
dagger: 1
arrow: 12
New Inventory:
rope: 1
torch: 6
gold coin: 42
dagger: 1
arrow: 12
x: 3
y: 1
z: 1
```

Question is, how can I convert x to gold coin y to dagger z to ruby then add all keys with their values? This code already took my like 2 hours, I am very newbie to CS and python. Any kind of help is appreciated.

I already did list to dictionary conversion and... took painfully a lot of time.

Comment: Inventory: rope: 1 torch: 6 gold coin: 42 dagger: 1 arrow: 12 + that new inventory. So that makes, 1 rope 54 golden coin, 43 dagger, 1 ruby, 12 arrow, 6 torch.

Comment: Never mind the math, I just want to convert x to gold coin y to dagger z to ruby then add all identical keys values together.